# Get current open Window on Titanium Alloy?

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, titanium-alloy

Is there a way to get the current open window?

In the controller is possible to use `this.getView()` to get that controller's relative view.

Since a controller can open any view in the project, I want not just know that controller's view, I want the top open (focused) view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access a view from it's accompanying controller by using $.getView(). If you want to access an item by id e.g. a TextField with id "myTextField" would be $.myTextField.

If you want to know the current top focused view then you should know that from what your app is doing -- as the controller / view you just opened would be the top most view.

Why do you need to know the top most view?

Comment: As I said via Slack: "App's structure is kinda mess and the app has no control of what is happening to view / controllers relationship."

Comment: App needs rewriting / refactoring -- Alloy apps shouldn't be a mess! ;)

Comment: This is one thing I really know. hehe
Any tips on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of all opened windows, preferably their controllers.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809490/1950810) might give you some insights.

Comment: In Alloy this is not necessary. You don't need to track all open windows and if you do this, and don't do it properly it can lead to memory leaks and other issues.

Comment: I'm not following, consider this scenario:

you want to display a view that would animate from the bottom of whatever the current window is, how can you get the window currently opened to embed that said view without tracking your open/close windows and always having a handle on the top most window ?

How is alloy gonna help  achieving this without tracking the open close calls on every window ? @jasonkneen ,thanks

Comment: YOU could create a transparent window that holds the view and just .open() that. I've user this technique to display progress indicators and toast notifications on iOS or Android.